# Vagrant + Parallels

Tags: vagrant, parallels

I know this has been asked in the past but things move fast and I'm wondering if, in the last few months, anyone has had luck either finding, using, or building a plug-in so that Vagrant can work with Parallels?  I've done a bit of searching and have not come up with anything except a github plug-in that is **not** being developed...

Also, I've messaged Parallels about this as I think it would be in their best interest to have a plug-in that works with Vagrant so as not to loose developers to lure of an easier life.  Will add in any details they provide.

Answer (score 4):

There is one in active development at https://github.com/yshahin/vagrant-parallels

Comment: I've been using this plugin for a week. There seems to be a problem with the networking and I have to restart the VMs regularly to get it working again.